# How many four digit integers either have a remainder of 2 when divided by 7, or a remainder of 4 when divided by 5, but not both?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Stuck on this one. Understand I need to find all x such that 999 < x < 10000 that satisfies either x mod 7 = 2 or x mod 5 = 4.

How can I do  this without actually solving?

Comment: **Hint:**  What is the largest number that satisfies $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ in the set $\{1000, 1001, \ldots, 9999\}$?  What is the largest number less than $1000$ that satisfies the same equivalence?

Comment: Hint 2: What are your solutions modulo 35? How many times does this fit your range, and what happens at the borders?

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  And do you know anything about Venn diagrams?

Comment: Do you mean that we wish to solve for the number of integers that satisfy exactly one of the congruences $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ and $x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ or the number of integers that satisfy $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ or $x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$, then $x = 2 + 7t$ for some integer $t$.  Since $10000 = 7 \cdot 1428 + 4$, the largest four-digit integer satisfying the congruence $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ is $9998 = 7 \cdot 1428 + 2$.  Since $1000 = 7 \cdot 142 + 6$, the largest three-digit integer satisfying the same congruence is $996 = 7 \cdot 142 + 2$.  Hence, there are $1428 - 142 = 1286$ four-digit positive integers satisfying the congruence $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$.

If $x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, then $x = 4 + 5s$ for some integer $s$.  The largest four-digit integer satisfying the congruence is $9999 = 5 \cdot 1999 + 4$.  The largest three-digit integer satisfying the congruence is $999 = 5 \cdot 199 + 4$.  Hence, there are $1999 - 199 = 1800$ positive four-digit integers satisfying the congruence $x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$.

If $x$ is an integer satisfying the system of congruences
\begin{align*}
x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}\\
x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}
\end{align*} 
then 
\begin{align*}
2 + 7t & \equiv 4 \pmod{5}\\
7t & \equiv 2 \pmod{5}\\
2t & \equiv 2 \pmod{5}\\
t & \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
\end{align*}
Since $t \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, $t = 1 + 5s$ for some integer $s$. Substituting $1 + 5s$ for $t$ yields $x = 2 + 7(1 + 5s) = 9 + 35s$.  Hence, if $x$ satisfies the system of congruences, then $x \equiv 9 \pmod{35}$.

Since $10000 = 285 \cdot 35 + 25$, the largest four-digit integer satisfying the congruence $x \equiv 9 \pmod{35}$ is $9984 = 285 \cdot 35 + 9$.  Since $1000 = 28 \cdot 35 + 20$, the largest three-digit integer satisfying the same congruence is $989 = 28 \cdot 35 + 9$.  Thus, the number of four-digit positive integers satisfying both congruences is $285 - 28 = 257$.

By the [Inclusion-Excluson Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of positive integers that satisfy $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ or $x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ is $1286 + 1800 - 257 = 2829$.  The number that satisfy exactly one of these congruences is $1286 + 1800 - 2 \cdot 257 = 2572$.

Answer (score 0):

List the numbers from 1000 to 1034. 1003, 1004, 1009, 1010, 1014, 1017, 1019, 1029, 1031 and 1034 meet one or the other of the criteria, so are acceptable by you; 1024 meets both criteria, so is inacceptable. The pattern repeats every 35 numbers. I hope you can do the rest.

Comment: I don't actually need to list them all. Just find out how many...

Comment: @ohbrobig \ I only listed the candidates in the first thirty-five numbers of your range so that you could have the fulfilling task of counting them, then determining how many such groups were in your four-digit range.

Answer (score 0):

Things are periodic with period $35$. Among $35$ consecutive numbers there are $7$ numbers having remainder $4$ mod $5$, $5$ numbers having remainder $2$ mod $7$, and $1$ number satisfying both conditions. It follows that there are exactly $11$ qualifying numbers among $35$ consecutive numbers.
There are $257*35$ numbers in the interval $[1005\>..\>9999]$, so that there are $257\cdot11=2827$ qualifying numbers in this interval. Add to these the numbers $1003$ and $1004$ which qualify as well, and obtain a total of ${\bf 2829}$ as final result.